# Default error popup with TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

Having a problem setting a different error message to EditText inside TextInputLayout.

What I get:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Is there anyway to achieve it while maintaining TextInputLayout?

Comment: Post your code xml and java

Comment: @marekxy You can use editText.setError("Error description");

Comment: Thanks for intrest but have managed to solve it, turns out i forgot i set the error on TextInputLayout before and all i needed was to swap it to setting the error on EditText

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i have allready solved it, i have wrote before in code:

```
((TextInputLayout) item_).setError(valid.getEventResult().getViewErrors()[i].getMessage().get_Message());
```

All i had to do was change it so i set the error on EditText instead of TextInputLayout.

Answer (score 0):

XML:

```
<TextInputLayout
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent">

     <EditText
          android:id="@+id/et"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</TextInputLayout>
```

JAVA:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);
if(et.getText().length() == 0){
    et.setError("Please Enter this Detail");
}
```